# Border image not displaying

Tags: html, css, image, border

I am using border image code something like this, but it is not working:

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:56px;
    font-family:arial;
    top:400px; left:200px;
    border-bottom-image:url(images/border_bg.png);
    -webkit-border-image:url(images/border_bg.png) 30 30 round; 
    -o-border-image:url(images/border_bg.png) 30 30 round;
    border-image:url(images/border_bg.png) 30 30 round;"
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">WE'VE GOT YOU COVERED.</div>
```

Comment: Take reference from this... http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: I think your code is working see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wKymx/ just copied your code and make a absolute image for test

Comment: OK, so how is it not working and what browsers are you testing on?

Comment: Means border image not displaying, I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have some syntax errors.

Here is a working example:

```
#container {
    font-size:56px;
    font-family:arial;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) 25% round;
}
```

You need to set a border width and style in order to create some space for the border image to appear.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JdEkB/

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the border style

```css
.border {
    border-image: url('border.png') 25% round;
    border-style: solid;
}
```